# Why do I have to flip the normals to make my solidify modifier's material index offset show up?

Tags: materials, modifiers, normals, solidify-modifier

[image]

[image]

The top picture is when the flip normals box is unchecked. The bottom picture is when the flip normals box is checked.

Comment: as you can see in your overwhelming comments and answers - you question might be a bit unclear. First we cannot see any material index in your pictures. so this doesn't show/prove anything to us. So maybe you wanna share your blend file and add a picture where we can see the material index you are talking about?

Comment: .. agreed.. please share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ , (editing the link into your question) to eliminate the variables as quickly as possible.